# How to convert a 3x3 rotation matrix into 4x4 matrix?

Tags: math, 3d, matrix, rotation

I'm currently using a 3x3 rotation matrix to work with 3D points.

How does this matrix differ from a 4x4 Matrix?

And how do I convert a 3x3 matrix into a 4x4?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A 4x4 matrix can be used to do both rotation and translation in a single matrix.

The `tx`, `ty` values down the right side of your matrix would be added to the x, y, z of the vertex you are transforming.

So to convert a 3x3 matrix to a 4x4, you simply copy in the values for the 3x3 upper left block, like so:

```
[ a11  a12  a13 ]
[ a21  a22  a23 ]
[ a31  a32  a33 ]
```

That 3x3 becomes this 4x4

```
[ a11  a12  a13  0 ]
[ a21  a22  a23  0 ]
[ a31  a32  a33  0 ]
[   0    0    0  1 ]
```

Notice in the 4x4 the upper left block got straight copied, and 0's were entered for the other new, extra entries (indicating I don't want any translation to be added).

Comment: any idea how I can convert a calculated 3x3 matrix into a 4x4?

Comment: Just copy the upper left 3x3 block directly into the same spots of the 4x4.  In your new 4x4, referring to the diagram above, make sure you put a `1` for `tw` and 0's for the rest of the bottom row, and 0's for each of tx, ty, tz.

Answer (score 5):

A 4x4 matrix will support *all* affine transforms, including rotation and translation.

See the answer to this question:  [Solution to skew bitmaps in flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772822/solution-to-skew-bitmaps-in-flash)

For the gory math, see:  http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/matrix4x4/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

A 4x4 matrix allows [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) of 3-dimensional vectors.