# OpenGL ES how to apply transformations from android.graphics.Matrix

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es

I have a 3x3 **android.graphics.Matrix**, and i want to apply all transformation to a 4x4 OpenGL Matrix for 2D transformations only. So far I have manage to apply rotation and scaling I am  using the example from the android team [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment) to render a triangle. I used this [class](https://github.com/slaviboy/InfiniteGridView/blob/master/infinitegridview/src/main/java/com/slaviboy/infinitegridview/MatrixGestureDetector.kt) for generating the android.graphics.Matrix, from finger gestures made by the user for **scale**, **move** and **translate** transformations.

After that I attach the [MatrixGestureDetector](https://github.com/slaviboy/InfiniteGridView/blob/master/infinitegridview/src/main/java/com/slaviboy/infinitegridview/MatrixGestureDetector.kt) on the onTouchEvent from the View. In the MyGLSurfaceView class:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView : GLSurfaceView {

    ...
    private val matrixGestureDetector = MatrixGestureDetector()

    override fun onTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        matrixGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)
        requestRender()
        return true
    } 
}
```

Then I used it to convert the **android.graphics.Matrix** to a OpenGL Matrix in the onDrawFrame method in 
**MyGLRenderer** class

```
    ...
    lateinit var matrixGestureDetector: MatrixGestureDetector

    override fun onDrawFrame(unused: GL10) {
            ...
             // get graphics matrix values
             val m = FloatArray(9)
             matrixGestureDetector.matrix.getValues(m)

             // set rotation and scaling from graphics matrix to form new 4x4 OpenGL matrix
             val openGLMatrix = floatArrayOf(
                    m[0], m[3], 0f, 0f,
                    m[1], m[4], 0f, 0f,
                    0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
                    0f, 0f, 0f, 1f
             )
             Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, openGLMatrix, 0)

             // draw shape, where scaling and rotation work
             mTriangle.draw(scratch)
    }
```

To apply the translation I have to add the **m[2]** and **m[5]** from the **android.graphics.Matrix** values and change the openGLMatrix to:

```
val openGLMatrix = floatArrayOf(
    m[0], m[3], 0f, 0f,
    m[1], m[4], 0f, 0f,
    0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
    m[2], m[5], 0f, 1f
)
```

Now the problem is that the OpenGL viewbox size is formed by coordinates in range [-1,1], look at the image below:
[image]

But the translation X and Y values from the **android.graphics.Matrix** are not in that range, to do that I changed it to:

```
val scaleX: Float = m[android.graphics.Matrix.MSCALE_X]
val skewY: Float = m[android.graphics.Matrix.MSKEW_Y] 
val translateX = m[android.graphics.Matrix.MTRANS_X]
val translateY = m[android.graphics.Matrix.MTRANS_Y]
val ratio = width.toFloat() / height

val openGLMatrix = floatArrayOf(
    m[0], m[3], 0f, 0f,
    m[1], m[4], 0f, 0f,
    0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
    -ratio * (translateX / width * 2), -(translateY / height * 2), 0f, 1f
)
```

Now translation work, but scale and rotation are not done on the pivot point(center point of rotation between the two fingers). How to apply all the transformation and is there a example code for 2D transformations for finger gestures that I can find anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figure out that there is miscalculations in the conversion from Graphic coordinate system to a OpenGL coordinate system for the translation. Here is the code for getting the accurate translation in a OpenGL coordinate system, set as separate functions:

```
fun normalizeTranslateX(x: Float): Float {

    val translateX = if (x < width / 2f) {
        -1f + (x / (width / 2f))
    } else {
         (x - (width / 2f)) / (width / 2f)
    }

    return -translateX * OpenGLRenderer.NEAR * ratio
}

fun normalizeTranslateY(y: Float): Float {

    val translateY = if (y < height / 2f) {
        1f - (y / (height / 2f))
    } else {
        -(y - (height / 2f)) / (height / 2f)
    }

    return translateY * OpenGLRenderer.NEAR
}
```

I have also updated the whole finger gesture transformation class, for generating the OpenGL matrix, with the applied transformations from the finger gestures here is the class [OpenGLFingerGestureTransformations](https://github.com/slaviboy/OpenGLFingerGestureTransformations/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/slaviboy/opengl/main/OpenGLMatrixGestureDetector.kt).

To get the OpenGL matrix first create your own **OpenGLMatrixGestureDetector** object, using the same way as creating MatrixGestureDetector:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView : GLSurfaceView {

    ...
    private val matrixGestureDetector = OpenGLMatrixGestureDetector()

    override fun onTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        matrixGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)
        requestRender()
        return true
    } 
}
```

Then in the **MyGLRenderer** class just generate the matrix with the method **transform()**

```
...
lateinit var matrixGestureDetector: OpenGLMatrixGestureDetector
private val transformedMatrixOpenGL: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)

override fun onDrawFrame(unused: GL10) {

   ...

   // get OpenGL matrix with the applied transformations, from finger gestures
   matrixGestureDetector.transform(mMVPMatrix, transformedMatrixOpenGL)

   // draw shapes with apply transformations from finger gestures
   mTriangle.draw(transformedMatrixOpenGL)
}
```

I have uploaded the full source code [HERE](https://github.com/slaviboy/OpenGLFingerGestureTransformations/).
Here is the final result:

[image]