# Add Z dimension to 2D Homogeneous Transform Matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, graphics, 3d

This is something I've been trying to work out for a while - I'm trying to go from a 2D x,y,w homogeneous transform matrix (eg. Android's graphics.matrix) and turn it into a 3D x,y,z,w transform matrix (eg. Android's opengl.matrix)

[Convert an android.graphics.Matrix to a GL mat4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797890/convert-an-android-graphics-matrix-to-a-gl-mat4) seems to be a similar question but the answer only applies to affine transformations while I need to handle perspective transformations in x and y. This also seems like something more general than a Android specific implementation.

I've tried making a system of equations to solve for what the 3D matrix values need to be such that for five points, the results for X and Y equal their value after the 2D transformation is applied and Z always equals one, but if the Z value is always left the same (what I want to happen) then the matrix is not invertible.

```py
import numpy as np

# arbitrary points to sample
# need 5 points to have 5 * 3d = 15 equations to solve for 15 matrix coefficents

x0 = -1
y0 = 1
z0 = 1
u0 = -1
v0 = 1
w0 = 1

x1 = 1
y1 = 1
z1 = 1
u1 = 1
v1 = 1
w1 = 1

x2 = 1
y2 = -1
z2 = 1
u2 = 1
v2 = -1
w2 = 1

x3 = -1
y3 = -1
z3 = 1
u3 = -1
v3 = -1
w3 = 1

x4 = 0
y4 = 0
z4 = 1
u4 = 0
v4 = 0
w4 = 1

# The following numbers seem to allow the calculation to finish but are not what i want
# x4 = 21
# y4 = 15
# z4 = 36
# u4 = 12
# v4 = 21
# w4 = 31

# matrix made by extending https://stackoverflow.com/a/57280136 into 3d

A = np.matrix([
    [x0, y0, z0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x0*u0, -y0*u0, -z0*u0],
    [x1, y1, z1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x1*u1, -y1*u1, -z1*u1],
    [x2, y2, z2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x2*u2, -y2*u2, -z2*u2],
    [x3, y3, z3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x3*u3, -y3*u3, -z3*u3],
    [x4, y4, z4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x4*u4, -y4*u4, -z4*u4],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, x0, y0, z0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x0*v0, -y0*v0, -z0*v0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, x1, y1, z1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x1*v1, -y1*v1, -z1*v1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, x2, y2, z2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x2*v2, -y2*v2, -z2*v2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, x3, y3, z3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x3*v3, -y3*v3, -z3*v3],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, x4, y4, z4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -x4*v4, -y4*v4, -z4*v4],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x0, y0, z0, 1, -x0*w0, -y0*w0, -z0*w0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x1, y1, z1, 1, -x1*w1, -y1*w1, -z1*w1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x2, y2, z2, 1, -x2*w2, -y2*w2, -z2*w2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x3, y3, z3, 1, -x3*w3, -y3*w3, -z3*w3],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x4, y4, z4, 1, -x4*w4, -y4*w4, -z4*w4]
])

print(A)
print(np.linalg.det(A)) # zero

b = np.array([u0, u1, u2, u3, u4, v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, w0, w1, w2, w3, w4])

c = np.linalg.solve(A, b) # crashes here

mat3d = np.matrix([
    [c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3]],
    [c[4], c[5], c[6], c[7]],
    [c[8], c[9], c[10], c[11]],
    [c[12], c[13], c[14], 1]
])

print(mat3d)
```

Is there a way to reliably extend a 2D homogeneous coordinates matrix to a 3D one?

Thanks!

Comment: I find this question still unclear: "Is there a way to reliably extend a 2D homogeneous coordinates matrix to a 3D one?" There are many ways, but it is unclear which properties are needed here. There is only a limited set of transformation properties which can be achieved by matrix multiplication in a homogeneous coordinate space.

Comment: "The results for X and Y equal their value after the 2D transformation is applied and Z always equals one, but if the Z value is always left the same (what I want to happen) then the matrix is not invertible" If you _want_ z to be mapped to a constant, then of course it is not invertible. But why do would you need it invertible then? As by your own specification, the inverse cannot exist. The 2D part of the mapping still can be inverted, though.

Comment: Do you mean you want to retain the 2D homogeneous transforms, i.e., projecting the result of the 3x3 matrix to (X/W, Y/W) while also being able to perform '3D' projections (perspective transforms for example) on the resulting (X/W, Y/W, (Z = const)) point?

Comment: @BrettHale I have a 2D (X/W, Y/W) perspective transformation matrix used for keystone correction that I was hoping to use in an openGl context where the current convention is that the image is rendered flat at a constant Z of 1. I'm worried that if Z is allowed to vary, that it could get confusing or parts of the texture would leave the clipping area.

Comment: @derhass The matrix being invertible was my failed attempt to work out what the expanded 4D matrix would be. I think you are correct that by definition it would not be possible to find this in the way I was trying to do it. Is there a way to find the proper 4D matrix values given the inverse of the 3D matrix?

Comment: @derhass The properties I was hoping to maintain was that the Scale, Skew, Perspective, and Translation of X and Y are kept from the original 3D (X/W, Y/W) matrix and that the new Z values are not affected by the perspective changes caused by X and Y. I am essentially trying to do a 2D operation for keystone correction on a flat texture floating at Z = 1

Comment: "s there a way to find the proper 4D matrix values given the inverse of the 3D matrix?" What are you trying to achieve here? Since there is only a single `w` you have to divide _all_ dimensions by, the prespective effect will always apply to `x`, `y` _and_ `z`. If you wanted some linear function in the z dimension (regarding the full transform of matrix-vector product follwed by perspecitve divide), you would in the general case need a non-linear mapping in z (before the divide), which simply can't be represented by a matrix-vector product.

Comment: @derhass Oh, that makes sense, I guess it's impossible then. I'll try to find a way to apply the transformation to the texture instead of doing it to the model. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: But the question is: do you _need_ it to by representable by a single matrix-vector product? Nothing is preventing you from for example setting `gl_Position.z = input.z * gl_Position.w`. However, you just need to be aware that then, the default interpolation for z will have the effect of bending your primitive in the z direction (will the corner points at the vertices stay correct), which might screw up the depth test and result in incorrect visibility if other primitves are close. But that effect can be fixed in the fragment shader (at the cost of losing early-z test, though).

Comment: But if just drawing a 2D texture distorted to a trapezoid, you're better off by using homogeneous space for the texture coordinates, and simply have your primitives form the correct 2D trapezoid shape in your 3D world.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, have a 3x3 matrix M1 and you want a 4x4 matrix M2, such that:

Wherever M1[x1,y1,w1] = [x2,y2,w2]...

You want M2[x1,y1,0,w1] = [x3,y3,z3,w3]...

Such that x2/w2 = x3/w3, y2/w2 = y3/w3, z3/w3 = 1

The easiest way is just to extend the matrix so that x3 = x2, y3 = y2, z3 = w2, w3 = w2.  To do that you just add a z column that is the same as the w column, and a z row that is all zeros