# Transform a 3X3 transform matrix to 4X4 matrix for css transform matrix3d

Tags: javascript, html, css, matrix, computer-vision

I have a 3X3 transform matrix that's the output of a [homography transform](https://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/#multiview).

I want to rotate and stretch a div according to this matrix but it looks like [css transform either receives a 4X4 matrix or a 2X3 matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

I tried to convert the 3X3 matrix by adding zeros and a one like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4833408/4279201) but it looks completley wrong (it's either making the div rotated by 90 degrees or if I do a transpose, too small).

How can I transform that 3X3 matrix such that css' transform will work correctly?

Comment: You can try your luck with gl-matrix: http://glmatrix.net/docs/ it can convert from 3x3 to 4x4, but be aware that projective matrices are not nessesarely convertable. 3x2 matrices are used for 2D transformations and 4x4 for 3D transformations.

Comment: oh and also be aware that css matrix has column-major order.

Comment: @Bellian I can't find it, where did you see that transformation in gl-matrix?

Comment: oh my bad.. it also only converts from 4x4 to 3x3.. sorry. can you set up a demo for testing anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some thougths that will propably help you:

There are a few possibilities concerning the matrix you recive:

---

The matrix is a 2D transformation matrix: In this case the matrix extension you do wil fail, because the matrix layout will look like this:

```
[x1, x2, tx]
[y1, y2, ty]
[0 , 0 , 1 ]
```

An extension would then look like this for a 4x4 matrix assuming that X and Y-axis dont change:

```
[x1, x2, 0, tx]
[y1, y2, 0, ty]
[0 , 0 , 1, 0 ]
[0 , 0 , 0, 1 ]
```

But since css is using a 2x3 matrix the last row is implied. So you can add them like this: `transform: matrix(x1,y1,x2,y2,tx,ty);` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix)

---

The matrix is a 3D rotation matrix: In this case the matrix extension you do wil fail, because the matrix layout will look like this:

```
[x1, x2, x3]
[y1, y2, y3]
[z1, z2, z3]
```

An extension would then look like this for a 4x4 matrix: (see the link in your question)

```
[x1, x2, x3, 0]
[y1, y2, y3, 0]
[z3, z3, z3, 0]
[0 , 0 , 0 , 1]
```

You can add them like this: `transform: matrix(x1,y1,z1,0, x2,y2,z2,0, x3,y3,z3,0, 0,0,0,1);` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix)

---

Last possibility: the Matrix is a projective one. No clue hot to handle this..

---

If i had to take a guess: By looking at this example (from the link you provided) I would say this is a 2D transformation matrix

**BE AWARE: the jsfeat lib has a row-major order, but css needs a column-major order!**

```js
var affine_kernel = new jsfeat.motion_model.affine2d();
var affine_transform = new jsfeat.matrix_t(3, 3, jsfeat.F32_t | jsfeat.C1_t);

var count = 33;
var from = [];
var to = [];
 
for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    from[i] = { "x":Math.random()*320, "y":Math.random()*240 };
    to[i] = { "x":from[i].x + 5, "y":from[i].y+5 };
}
affine_kernel.run(from, to, affine_transform, count);

var a = [...affine_transform.data.subarray(0 , 6)];
b = [
  0.08420821279287338,
  -0.03247755020856857,
  14.28314018249511,
  -0.009080140851438,
  0.11894367635250,
  7.15110540390014,
  -0.00034110905835,
  -0.01147077046,
  1
];

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById('to-transform');
  elem.style.transform = 'matrix('+a[0]+','+a[3]+','+a[1]+','+a[4]+','+a[2]+','+a[5]+')';
  
  var mat = [b[0],b[3],0,b[6], b[1],b[4],0,b[7], 0,0,1,0, b[2],b[5],0,b[8] ]
  var elem1 = document.getElementById('to-transform2');
  elem1.style.transform = 'matrix3d('+mat.join(',')+')';
})
```

```css
.container {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  
  background: #aaa;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.to-transform {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  
  background: #a00;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 92px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/js/jsfeat-min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="to-transform" class="to-transform">to-transform</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="to-transform2" class="to-transform">to-transform2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a projective matrix https://imgur.com/a/tDRZi. Here's an example of this matrix values: [0.08420821279287338,-0.03247755020856857,14.283140182495117,-0.009080140851438046,0.11894367635250092,7.1511054039001465,-0.0003411090583540499,-0.011470770463347435,1]

Comment: I have updated the example and attempted the extension but cant say if this is the right approach. Do you know how the transformed element should look like?

Comment: Not really, that matrix does strange things on matlab... How did you get to this matrix transformation (the way you added the zeros)?

Comment: Lite i said: `Last possibility: the Matrix is a projective one. No clue hot to handle this..` I just extended the Matrix into 3D space setting all z related components 0. Sorry cant help you there..

Comment: My div size is 640, 480 and it's going crazy if I do that (also happens if I change the sizes in your answer). Do you know of a way to use that projection matrix and source points (x,y) to get destination points? I thought maybe this could help: http://jlouthan.github.io/perspective-transform/examples/css-matrix3d/index.html