# How to convert the OpenCV GetPerpectiveTransform Matrix into a CSS Matrix?

Tags: python, css, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a matrix from the Python Open-CV library:

`M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(source_points, points)`

But it is completely different from the [CSS Transform Matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix)
Even though it has the same shape I think open-cv does some kind of other translations to x and y depending on the scale and skew of the numbers.
Example:
I have an Image in the source points (green) and the target points(orange)

[image]

With `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(source, target)` I get the matrix:

```
array([[ 7.45735546e-01, -8.09538161e-02,  1.02930118e+01],
       [-4.69040997e-01,  8.60285055e-01,  7.66245963e+01],
       [-6.90849647e-04, -3.31231543e-04,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

And finally the `cv2.wrapPerspective` I get my image:

[image]

but if I try that same matrix with CSS transform, using the homogeneous matrix `transform: matrix(0.74574, -0.46904, -0.08095, 0.86029, -88.57274000000001, -102.30782)` and the same values of the cv2 matrix I get:

[image]

I tried to search for the `getPerpectiveTransform` algorithm but I just found examples on how to use it.
What I’m missing?

Comment: Are you sure CSS Transform Matrix supports matrix with a last line that is not [0, 0, 1]? The closest CSS matrix is `[0.7457, -0.4690, -0.0810, 0.8603, 10.2930, 76.6246]`, but it applies Affine Transform and not Perspective Transform.

Comment: according to this, CSS can do it. recipe: https://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform a 3X3 transform matrix to 4X4 matrix for css transform matrix3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038052/transform-a-3x3-transform-matrix-to-4x4-matrix-for-css-transform-matrix3d)

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour]. you don't have the corresponding badge yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the help of [computing CSS matrix3d](https://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/).
The resultant matrix is the same from the `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform` you must use it with [transform: matrix3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix3d) and transform-origin: -left px -up px.

The left up pixels are the origin points from the upper left corner in negative as the origin is in 0,0 and you are substracting the origin corner

[image]